# Why does Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier has already been declared error occurs?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and currently trying to build a timer. I am using JS when I encountered a problem on the very first line, it said that my function has already been declared when it hasn't. I read lots of other stack questions related to this error but none seems to have the same problem. Here is my code:

```
const timer = () => { // This is where the error occurs.
  const song = document.querySelectorAll(".song"); 
  const play = document.querySelector(".play");
  const reset = document.querySelectorAll(".reset");

  // Time display
  const minuteDisplay = document.querySelectorAll(".minute");
  const secondDisplay = document.querySelectorAll(".second");

  //Duration
  const formDuration = 20;
  let duration = formDuration * 60;

  let displayMinutes = ("0" + Math.floor(duration / 60)).slice(-2);
  let displaySeconds = ("0" + Math.floor(duration % 60)).slice(-2);

  for (const mdisplay in minuteDisplay) {
    mdisplay.textContent = `${displayMinutes}`;
  }

  for (const sdisplay in secondDisplay) {
    sdisplay.textContent = `${displaySeconds}`;
  }

  play.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkPlaying(song);
  });

  const checkPlaying = (song) => {
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      play.textContent = `Pause`;
      play.classList.toggle("btn-active");
    } else {
      song.pause();
      play.innerHTML = `Play`;
      play.classList.remove("btn-active");
    }
  };

  song.ontimeupdate = () => {
    let currentTime = song.currentTime;
    let elapsed = duration - currentTime;
    let seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);
    let minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);

    // Edit time display
    formatMinutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
    formatSeconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
    minuteDisplay.textContent = `${formatMinutes}`;
    secondDisplay.textContent = `${formatSeconds}`;

    reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
      song.pause();
      song.currentTime = 0;
      play.innerHTML = `Play`;
      play.classList.remove("btn-active");
      if (reset.classList.contains("btn-active")) return;
      reset.classList.add("btn-active");
      // remove class after 2 seconds
      setTimeout(() => {
        reset.classList.remove("btn-active");
      }, 150);
    });

    if (currentTime >= duration) {
      song.pause();
      song.currentTime = 0;
      play.innerHTML = "Play";
      play.classList.remove("btn-active");
    }
  };
};

timer();
```

I am confused as how to solve this error, so any feedback will be greatly appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: Does exists an output on browsers console? If so, wich line will be marked?

Comment: Hi Brian, I think you'll find you'll be more likely to get help if you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes it does, it marks the first line of code. Now I have changed it from 
const timer = () => { 
to just 
function timer() {
The error seems to be resolved but now the code inside doesn't seem to be applied to the website. Do you have any idea why this change might stop the code from working properly? 

Hi, Brendan. Sure let me try to edit the question... Sorry if it is long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I checked your when you are using querySeelctorAll it returns array so before adding addEventListener you have to do for loop like this

let's do it for reset button:

```
  const reset = document.querySelectorAll(".reset");
```

and now first for loop

```
reset.forEach(resetButton => {
    resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      song.pause();
      song.currentTime = 0;
      play.innerHTML = `Play`;
      play.classList.remove("btn-active");
      if (reset.classList.contains("btn-active")) return;
      reset.classList.add("btn-active");
      // remove class after 2 seconds
      setTimeout(() => {
        reset.classList.remove("btn-active");
      }, 150);
    });
})
```

Or you can use loop like this:

```
for(const resetButton of reset) {
   resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          song.pause();
          song.currentTime = 0;
          play.innerHTML = `Play`;
          play.classList.remove("btn-active");
          if (reset.classList.contains("btn-active")) return;
          reset.classList.add("btn-active");
          // remove class after 2 seconds
          setTimeout(() => {
            reset.classList.remove("btn-active");
          }, 150);
        });
}
```

Hope this would help.
And for debugging why "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier has already been declared error occurs" happens I need to have your HTML part too.
let me know when you updated the code